# Unable to autoconnect to hidden network in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, internet, connection

My computer with Ubuntu 15.04 is unable to automatically connect to hidden wireless network. I have checked the "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" option, but it doesn't work and I have to manually connect every time after booting.

Sometimes also a window asking for the network's password appears on the Ubuntu log-in screen at start-up.

Is there a way to autoconnect to hidden network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved the issue on 15.04 release, but update the system to Ubuntu 16.04 has made the problem disappear.